# Null propagating function type annotation

Tags: typescript

In this scenario, we have a function which formats a date, but also propagates nulls:

```
function DateToIso(d: Date | null) {
    return d === null ? null : SugarDate.format(d, '%F');
}
```

I'd like to be able to call this function and have the return type match the nullability of the provided parameter.  For example, this doesn't work – but should in my happy little world.

```
const nowIso: string = DateToIso(new Date());
```

How can I specify the function so that the above works, while still allowing propagation of nulls?

Comment: Add overload to your func

Comment: @captain-yossarian, Overload yields "Duplicate function implementation."  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQIZQKYBU4EkDOcAFACYBci+UATjGAOaIA+iYIANuwJSIDeAsAChEIxNQxQQ1JCUQBeBaw7tEAfiWdEFEgDooeAMoB5AzTr0iXANxCAvkKGhIsBCnTY8hUhSq0GPAWFRcUlpRF19XGNTPwtrOwdBNEwcAmI2TnjBCAQqSh8zBnk3FM90jAB3EoxLayA

Comment: You should not write an actual implementation in overload, only return type

Comment: @captain-yossarian,  Ah.  I see.  Feel free to post as answer.  (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQIZQKYBU4EkDOcAFACYBcK6GAlBflAE4xgDmA3ALABQoksClTDgLFygjIgA+iMCAA2c2onpNWUmfLmce4aPCRoheQqQqGJ02QuqIA3t0SPEDDFBAMkJRAF5fGhYgA-P5yiBQkAHRQeADKAPIxjMwsRNTaAL7c3ObCJlaK2hAI9Mp0SWre4rnEYBgA7uKpaUA)

Comment: look to the  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQIZQKYBU4EkDOcAFACYBcK6GiAPomCADaMCUZ+UATjGAOY0NmiAN4AoRBMQxgRAIQkWYycsTiVEzhighOSQYzUSAvqMOJN23YhIA6KHDSYAylx68iLUSdMQEhRhg2jHDujth4hET6LJ6+YP6BwaFUOATEYBgA7pSYHjFAA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use overloads:

```js
function DateToIso(d: Date): string;
function DateToIso(d: null): null;
function DateToIso(d: Date | null):string | null {
    return d === null ? null : d.toISOString();
}

const withNull = DateToIso(null); // null
const withString = DateToIso(new Date()); // string
```

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQIZQKYBU4EkDOcAFACYBcK6GAlBflAE4xgDmA3ALABQoksClTDgLFyiMCAA2k2uKmTOPcNHhI0QvIVIV1GRAB8502vSasDRyYgDe3RPcQMMUEAyQlEAXm%20XEAfl8KEgA6KDwAZQB5cMZmFiJqRQBfbm4IBHpEAHcYKAALADl5L0FsTWIJYzZEAHoayzSMqGzcvJizFhLdYS0wDCzShMTa%20tM4oA)

Btw, you dont need to use explicit types here `const nowIso: string = DateToIso(new Date());`. TS in most cases is able to infer that

Comment: That seems does not do all the compiler checks. You could do something like `return d === null ? null : (d.getSeconds() % 2 === 0) ? null : d.toISOString();` so it will be possible to have `null` in the `withString` variable which leads to unchecked null-pointer exceptions.

Comment: @kan function overloading signatures are bivariant, it means that it is not 100% safe. It is developer responsibility make them reflect function body. TS is not sound language

Comment: For me it defeats the purpose then... My thinking was to have a compiler checks so it proves null-safety... I would suggest to use different functions like `DateToIso` for non-nulls and `DateToIsoNullable` for `Date | null` argument type.

Comment: You can get rid of overloading signatures and leave it as is. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/NrKX0m). If you want to make sure that your app is 100% type safe it worth considering ReScript or Fable

Comment: No, you cannot. The `const nowIso: string = DateToIso(new Date());` stops working.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you use explicit type `string` for `nowIso` ? You don't know return value of `getSeconds()`

Comment: It is just a demo. I.e. in a call-context you may know you have non-nullable argument, then there is no point to do null-checks for result. E.g. in such scenario there are no nulls and no null-checks are needed: `DateToIso(new Date()).toLowerCase()`. But in different scenario you may just want to propagate nullables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241641/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-kan).

Answer (score 0):

Seems suggestion using overloads does not guarantee null-safety. I suggest to use two different functions and call the corresponding one depending on context:

```
function DateToIso(d: Date) {
    return SugarDate.format(d, '%F');
}

function DateToIsoNullalbe(d: Date | null) {
    return d === null ? null : DateToIso(d);
}
```

Maybe you decide to use a wrapper to lift any non-nullable function to nullable. Something like

```
function wrapNullable<T, R>(f: (t: T) => R): (t: T | null) => (R | null) {
    return t => t === null ? null : f(t);
}
```

So you could do `wrapNullable(DateToIso)(xxx)`

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOA5EAbPdAIzwFMAeAFQBpEAlAPgApgAuRJqdygSkQF4G9Hu07dEAH0Rh8ePoI51J02XwDeAWABQiXYlSkoIVEigChZ-lZUFEAfht5E7YJx4BubQF9t20JFgERAARdChSSjgASQBnOCYAE3ZQ8PVtPX1DYyQEgDooaIBlAHlCqFQYMABzJg9vXy1K8NRgdAhSRABRADdSMChNHUQYqHRUKBTSZLDSTyG+hMnp8OUZAjmfLW0m0ha2joAxOFQAWzDwhJ6+s0HdEbGJmfYRiuq53QWl4fLKqtXZDYNfzQeBIYDHM5QK79JhTLq9fp8dhHU7nUiXBE3dKZIwmRC3DLfB5fSaRWLxUi5e7jSY8ajYjKfJ4oDA4WTEMhMUnROI8WG5JmpbGbTZAA)

I guess it's even better as it does not have null check condition when it's known you don't need them. May improve performance... theoretically at least.